# How to add checkbox in my gridview?

Tags: android

How do I add check box in my grid view, I am using simple adapter so what do I do? How I add check box in my grid please help me how I add check box in my code can anyone help me?
How to add checkbox in gridview so user selected multiple pictures

```
 SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;
     GridView gridView;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    File photos = new File(getFilesDir(),"photos");
    photos.mkdirs();

    File root1 = new File("/data/data/com.newsoftwares.folderlock/files/");

    currentParent = root1;
    currentFiles = root1.listFiles();

    currentFilePath = new String[currentFiles.length];
    int count = 0;

    for(File f:currentFiles)
    {   
        currentFilePath[count] = f.getAbsolutePath();
        count++;
    }


    gridView =(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
        position,long id) {


        if(currentFiles[position].isDirectory())
        {
            root = new File("/data/data/com.myexample.folderlock
         /files/"+FileName(currentFilePath[position])+"/");

            Log.e("Root first",root+ " ");

            currentFiles = root.listFiles();

            inflateListView(currentFiles);
        }
        else if(currentFiles[position].isFile())
        {
              inflateListView(currentFiles);    
                   }

        private void inflateListView(File[] files){

List<Map<String,Object>> listItems = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();

for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
{       
        Map<String, Object> listItem = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        if(files[i].isDirectory())
        {
            listItem.put("icon", R.drawable.folder);
        }
        else
        {
            listItem.put("icon", R.drawable.file);
        }

        listItem.put("fileName", files[i].getName());
        listItems.add(listItem);
    }

    simpleAdapter=new SimpleAdapter(this,listItems,R.layout.line,new String[] 
     {"icon","fileName"},new int[]{R.id.icon,R.id.file_name});
    gridView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
     sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" 
        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

you couldn't do it in gridview but u can do it in listview

here is the main activity

```
package com.example.checkboxingridview;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView checkboxList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        checkboxList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        checkboxList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects));

    }

    // do what you want if this item checked
    void checkBoxChecked(View v) {
        CheckBox checkbox= (CheckBox)v;
        Object rowObject =checkbox.getTag();
        // here we can do what we want in this checkbox
    }


}
```

and the custom adapter

```
package com.example.checkboxingridview;

import java.util.List;

import com.example.pos.R;
import com.util.TransactionCustomAdapter.ViewHolder;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
        List objects) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();



        holder.setCheckBox((CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1));


        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    // set tag by the object of this list item
    holder.voidBtn.setTag(itemListObject);

    // StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
    // StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
    // .permitAll().build();
    // StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    CheckBox checkBox;

    public CheckBox getCheckBox() {
        return checkBox;
    }

    public void setCheckBox(CheckBox checkBox) {
        this.checkBox = checkBox;
    }

}
```

}

the main_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
</ListView>
```