# please help me how to customise gridview

Tags: android

I am using a simple adapter in my code. I'm populating a `GridView` from file path.  Below is my code, which works. Now I want to add a checkbox in my gridview.  How can I do that? How should I modify my code?  All examples I find import images from gallery, but I need to import them form file path. If a file is a directory, I further need to show a directory icon, otherwise show an image.

```
GridView gridView;
TextView textView;
File currentParent;
File[] currentFiles;
SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;
File root1;
File root;

root1 = new File("/data/data/com.myexample.lock/files/");

currentParent = root1;
currentFiles = root1.listFiles();

currentFilePath = new String[currentFiles.length];
int count = 0;

for (File f : currentFiles) {
    currentFilePath[count] = f.getAbsolutePath();
    count++;
}

gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (currentFiles[position].isDirectory()) {
            root = new File("/data/data/com.myexample.lock/files/" + FileName(currentFilePath[position]) + "/");
            currentFiles = root.listFiles();
            inflateListView(currentFiles);
        } else if (currentFiles[position].isFile()) {
            openFile(currentFiles[position]);
        }
    }
});


private void inflateListView(File[] files) {
    List<Map<String, Object>> listItems = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        Map<String, Object> listItem = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
            listItem.put("icon", R.drawable.folder);
            listItem.put("fileName", files[i].getName()+"("+files[i].list().length+")");
        } else {
            listItem.put("icon", files[i]);
        }

        listItems.add(listItem);
    }

    simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, R.layout.line,new String[] { "icon", "fileName" }, new int[] { R.id.icon, R.id.file_name });
}
```

R.layout.line.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/file_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/icon"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you heard about the notion of sentences?

Comment: @hayyaanam Please try to avoid shorthands and abbreviations like *plzz, im etc* in your questions.. You are not writing messages to your friends, instead your asking for help from other proffessionals..Write proper sentence with correct use of capital letters.

Comment: can u give a sample file from which you want to populate the grid

Comment: my all code is there u mean can i mail u my code? give me ur email addresss

Comment: my code is above u can see above i used to call grid like that

Comment: Your question is lot of confusing. Anyways if you wnat to add a checkbox you will have to create an CustomAdapter instead of the SimpleAdapter.

Comment: ok i understand but tell me in custom adapter how do i diffrenciate is directory or file???

Comment: like my code im loading images from filepath so give me any example like that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129709/how-to-add-checkbox-in-my-gridview?rq=1). customise gridview with check box as expected in your application.

Comment: that code is also mine which solution u give me but problem is im using simpleadapter that code used custom adaptter which not diffrenciate current file is  directory or file?   if is directory show folder icon otherwise show image how do i diffrenciate like that in ur code??